# How to transform an uniform distribution into a generalized beta 2 distribution using gamlss, fitdist or other?

Tags: r, distributions, gamlss

Not comfortable with math and just R beginner, I get stuck on the following problem:

Imagine that, for a variable `ya` (n=3000), the gamslss `fitDist` function selects the GB2 distribution with e.g. mu=2, sigma=4, nu=4, tau=1.

```
library(gamlss)
ya<- rGB2(3000, mu=2, sigma=4, nu=4, tau=1) #for example
hist(ya,200)
```

Imagine now a second variable yb (n=800) with an uniform distribution

```
yb <- runif(800, 0, 20)
hist(yb,200)
```

Question: What is the easiest way to transform `yb` so that its uniform distribution becomes similar to the generalized beta 2 distribution from `ya`, with similar mu, sigma, nu, and tau?

I guess it requires some integration / function (using gamlss, fitdistplus or other?), but I don't know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generic way to solve this problem (converting a set of uniform random deviates to an alternative probability distribution) is to use the *inverse cumulative distribution function* or *quantile function*: this is also called [inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling).

`gamlss` provides a `qGB2()` function that plays this role.

In this case we have to scale the uniform variates to (0,1) (dividing by the max value=20) before quantile-transforming:

```r
plot(density(ya))
lines(density(qGB2(yb/20,mu=2, sigma=4, nu=4, tau=1)),col=2)
```

[image: densities of distributions overlaid]

**Bonus**: if you look at the code in `gamlss::rGB2`, you'll see that in fact *this is exactly what `gamlss` does in the first place to generate GB2-distributed variates*!

```r
p <- runif(n)
r <- qGB2(p, mu = mu, sigma = sigma, nu = nu, tau = tau)
```